# What is the difference between axial compressor blades and centrifugal compressor blades?

Tags: general-aviation, compressor, blade

Is there a particular difference?  The way they're overhauled is the same ? (I mean do we use the same overhauling methods ?)

Answer (score 4):

The blades are shaped completely differently. Typically a centrifugal compressor is one solid piece that looks like a turbocharger and an axial compressor is a flat disk that looks like a fan with individually manufactured blades inserted, though axial compressor disks with integral blades "blisk" is starting to be used. Here are compressor pics that show how they are used:

Two stage radial/centrifugal compressor circled (with a three stage axial turbine following)
[image]

Fifteen stage axial compressor
[image]

A radial compressor can usually generate higher pressure in a single stage so it's usually simpler, while an axial compressor is easier to stack in multiple stages to get much higher pressure ratios.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is in how they operate, vs how they are maintained. Flow through a centrifugal compressor is turned perpendicular to the axis of rotation, while air in an axial compressor flows parallel to the axis of rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Axial blades are airfoils that compress air by forcing it aft into a converging space via downwash the same as a wing generates lift by downwash.  Efficient, but sensitive to angle of attack and aerodynamic stall, like a regular wing, so therefore sensitive to flow disruptions.

A centrifugal compressor is spinning duct that forces air into a converging space purely by centrifugal force imparted to air within it as it spins.  Less efficient, but relatively insensitive to flow disruptions and way easier to make.

Comment: Axial blades do not have to be airfoils.

Comment: Do you know of a turbine engine with flat ones?